# On Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1, touch events within iframe are ignored on elements when there are content before the iframe

Tags: galaxy-tab

In my testpage, http://finlir.net/paint/kinetic/2height.html I have bound touchstart event to two div elements. When touching the elements at that page on my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 stock browser, the events are recognised and some debug text is printed. But, when I use an iframe to show that page http://finlir.net/paint/kinetic/2heightiframe.html the events are not fired, when I press on an element at the lower part of the iframe. Depending on how much space that is used before the iframe affects this, more space used before the iframe seems to make less "touchable space" in the iframe. On my iframe-testpage (see second link above) this can be tested by pressing the button "add p".

Any idea what causes this problem? I have no problems on iPad, iPhone, my Android HTC Desire etc.

**Update:** I wrapped all stuff within the iframe in a div with overflow hidden, and set its width and height to the window (iframe) size. I then added padding:100000px at the right and bottom of one of the elements. Now the touches are detected.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Samsung on a similar issue, and found out that iframes is not fully compatible with their os. I was having a problem with scrolling. All of the links that were out of frame before I scrolled down did not work, and there was a permanent ghost-link of the previous links within the frame. Recently though Samsung released a major update and it seemed to have fixed my problem, which is great because my GreenLinks app is now compatible!

Comment: Thanks for the information, nice to hear your problem is solved in new versions. I finally got around my problem by setting a huge padding on the right and bottom of my content and then wrapping everything in a fixed width container same size as iframe with overflow hidden.